# R code to create a custom similarity type matrix

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix

This is for all the R guru's:

I want to make a function that finds the the minimum value between the same observation of one column and another column in a matrix. It must then sum all these minimum values and put the answer into a new matrix. This should be done between all columns of the original matrix.

In other words, I start off with a matrix of n observations (rows) and m variables. Then for column 1 and 2 I want to find the minimum value between each pair of observations, and then sum the minimum values to get an answer. This must be done successively bewtween the first column and every other column. Then between the second column and every other column etc. Like a type of similarity matrix.

I have attached an image of the formula I want to implement (for observation i between column j and column k). Any help would be appreciated!!! (hope you understand, I find it very difficult to explain properly) [Formula to be implemented in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCCUc.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

It's easier for us to help you if you give an example dataset and the desired output, but here is my take on it:

```
mat <- matrix(sample(1:12),nrow = 4)
colnames(mat) <- c("v1","v2","v3")
mat
     v1 v2 v3
[1,]  8  4  1
[2,]  5 12  6
[3,] 10  2 11
[4,]  9  7  3

minsum <- function(c1,c2) sum(apply(mat[,c(c1,c2)],1,min))

outer(1:ncol(mat),1:ncol(mat),Vectorize(minsum))

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   32   18   19
[2,]   18   25   12
[3,]   19   12   21
```

off-diagonals are the results of your formula/algorithm, diagonals are column sums.